# How to translate "por la cara" to English?

Tags: meaning, expressions, translation, spanish

I'm looking for a suitable English translation of the Spanish expression "**por la cara**".

In Spanish, unless you go very deep into the details, for various context that are   very specific, generally, "por la cara" can have two relevant meanings (I think); those are the following:

1. There is no specific reason for something to happen, it just happens - e.g. You get out of your home and see an elephant in the street. In Spanish, you would say that the elephant is in the street "por la cara", meaning "**out of the blue**".
2. There is no reason for you to get something, but you still get it - e.g. Your brother came back home from shopping and got you an ice-cream without you asking for it. In Spanish, you would say he got you the ice-cream "por la cara", meaning "**just because**".

I'm very interested in this second meaning and what would be the best translation to English.

Even though I used "just because" which I think can be a very good option for the translation of "por la cara", I've seen other options such as "**because reasons**" or "**for the hell of it**". However,  I'm not completely sure that this latter  has the right meaning.

Therefore, for meaning number 2, I was wondering what translation would be best:

- just because
- because reasons
- for the hell of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124012/discussion-on-question-by-marina-morales-how-to-translate-por-la-cara-to-engli).

Comment: I’m not sure translation is on topic here. Your question in my opinion contains an on-topic question in describing a situation and asking for a suitable word, although you should make it clear that you are offering suggestions, not choices. None of them work for me in this context.

Comment: expressions are used on contexts. Your provide none. So, it's really a fool's errand.

Comment: '[Well,] why not?' is a general response to such an open-ended question.  For your other question, the well-known English expression 'Que sera, sera' is often used. Or the hyper-literal (and hence now considered faintly amusing) 'Now _there's_ something you don't see very often'.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific context of an explanation for an unanticipated small treat of the type described, the following might work in English.

> “I bought it on impulse”

or using simpler language;

> “I bought it just because I felt like it”

Don’t try to translate by word or phrase replacement.